# Building and running a single .cpp file in Netbeans without having to create a project?

Tags: c++, netbeans, compiler-construction, ide, cygwin

I was wondering if you can help me out. I've recently started using Netbeans to code in c++. After I installed the Cygwin compiler, I've found that in order to build and run c++ code one has to create a whole project.

Is there a way that I can only build and run ONE single .cpp file or is it necessary to make a whole project for only one file?

If that is the case, do you know about any other IDE's that can build and run a SINGLE .cpp file without having to create a project for one file?

Thank you.

Comment: The NetBeans "C++ Project with Existing Sources" will require you to have *two* files - your `SINGLE.cpp` and `Makefile`. It's not so bad, you'll need the `Makefile` anyway. The project directory will have a `nbproject` subdirectory as well, but you won't need to look inside it.

Comment: Thanks! I managed with code::blocks. When I get more intense projects or assignments I will use the Netbeans IDE. Thank you for your reply.